# Spark SQL 2.3 - Slow search results for LIKE '%message%'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I get log4j format logs, process them and store them in Spark. I am not in clustered or multi node environment. Using Spark as a single node application. I am just a beginner in spark, learning the concepts by writing an application. Instead of DB(MySQL) i am using Spark as backend, so that the processing would be much much faster than DB(for millions of records). I hope this is fine.

Using Spark SQL, trying to fetch the records with below query.

```
qry = qry + " error LIKE '%" + errormsg + "%' ";
List<Row> allrows = logDataFrame.filter(qry).collectAsList();
```

Currently Spark is holding 1 million records. This query is taking **6 seconds** to fetch 1000 records.

Is this the wrong usage of Spark ? I don't think so, this is where spark has to **process** the records and fetch the records as quick as possible. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

I am confused why it's taking this long to fetch records.

Do i need to tweak any configurations to Spark or anything else ? Please suggest.

Using my application in error mode:

```
SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the wrong usage of Spark?

That's just an opinion but I'd say it definitely is. What you seem to look for is either database with full text search capabilities or search engine, not Spark, which is not designed to be used as either of these.

Despite having SQL component, it is for sure not a replacement for MySQL.

> I don't think so, this is where spark has to process the records and fetch the records as quick as possible.

This is not the use case for Spark. While Spark slowly evolves into low(er) latency streaming engine, it is was never designed for low latency interactive queries. It is primarily optimized for volume, not speed.

While some equality based based predicates can be optimized with the right storage, queries like string matching have to check every row of data, making this process very expensive.

Comment: can you pls suggest any alternative to achieve this ? i don't want DB, i am in process to develop a desktop application which doesn't require any other servers or services should be started externally. Just a single JVM should accommodate everything.